# Android AltBeacon False Positives Exit Region

Tags: android, altbeacon

I'm using the AltBeacon library to monitor a beacon region and get notified when it enters and exits the region. The problem is I sometimes we get a false "ExitRegion" event. At times I also don't receive an "EnterRegion" event.

For example, I might get the "ExitRegion" event while the beacon is plugged into power.

I saw this issue posted in the library but we didn't see a solution/suggestion posted on the thread: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/609

I haven't changed any settings on the beacon itself. I'm using `RegionBootstrap` and I've read the docs as well.

Are there any suggestions or gotchas that might be affecting us? How could we solve these false positives for exit region? Anything we might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have any success with the suggested solutions?  If so, you could mark the answer as accepted and maybe post an update sharing what worked.

Answer (score 1):

False region exits are a common problem, not just with the Android Beacon Library but with iOS Core Location and other detection frameworks, too.

The fundamental cause is failure of the Bluetooth scanner on the phone to detect a beacon advertising packet in a certain amount of time, (30 secs sets n iOS, 10 secs on the Android Beacon Library, but configurable).  This has a number of possible reasons across all detection frameworks:

- An infrequently advertising beacon that does not send out packets often enough.
- A beacon signal that is so weak (either because it is far away or because it is set to transmit at low power) that is is rarely detected.
- A faulty Bluetooth antenna, chip, or Bluetooth stack on the phone.

With the Android Beacon Library, it is also possible to customize scan intervals in a way that could cause this problem. For best results in most cases, you should accept the defaults.

Other tips:

1. Configure your beacons to advertise as many packets per second as possible.
2. Configure your beacon to advertise at the highest transmitter power level possible.
3. Move the beacon closer to the phone.
4. Try a different phone to see if the problem is device-specific.

Comment: thanks davidyoung will try these suggestions and try with other phones as well